# Hide modal by clicking outside of the modal | react-native

Tags: react-native

[image]
I want to hide the modal that by clicking anywhere in the `ScrollView` component.  I have tried with Wrapping all the components inside `ScrollView` with a `View` and Wrapping the view with `TouchableWithoutFeed`. But when the modal pop's this Touchable seems to not working at all.

Comment: Have you tried to put vies in position absolut underneat with touchable ? Wrap the modal in it. Inside the scroll view

Answer (score 0):

When the `ScrollView`'s `onClick()` is hit, you can toggle the components state `showMoreModal` to false. This will hide the modal.

```
<ScrollView onClick={()=>{
    if(this.state.showMoreModal){
        this.setState({showMoreModal:false});
    }
}}>
...
<Confirm/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

First do not use `Modal` inside `ScrollView`. Add `TouchableWithoutFeedback` inside modal to hide/close modal.

```
return (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView>
      {...} <-------- Scroll Content
    </ScrollView>
    <Modal>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}
      >
        <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0}}>
          {...} <-------- Modal Content
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Modal>
  </View>
);
```